# sup and inf of $A=\left\{\frac{m^4+2n^2}{2m^2-m^2n+n^2}:m,n \in\Bbb N\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$$A=\left\{\frac{m^4+2n^2}{2m^2-m^2n+n^2}:m,n \in\Bbb N\right\}$$

$\sup A$ doesn't exist, because $A$ is not bounded above:

$$\begin{align}n&=1 \\
\frac{m^4+2}{m^2+1} &\le M \\
\frac{m^4+2}{m^2} &\le M \\
m^2+\frac{2}{m^2} &\le M \\
m^2&\le M\end{align}$$

But I can choose $m=\lfloor M \rfloor+1$ from Archimedean property.

I think $\inf A=3/2$. Am I right?

UPDATE: for $m=3$ and $n=4$ we get $-113/2$

UPDATE2: I think $\inf A$ doesn't exist too.
I have to prove that e.g:

$$\forall _m \exists _n:m^2n>n^2+2m^2$$

Comment: About your first comment: then $\;\sup A=\infty\;$ ...isn't it? But you say "it doesn't exist"...and your question ends with $\;\sup A=\frac32\;$ . This is pretty confusing...and contradictory.

Comment: Sorry, It was only a typo.

Comment: Do you have any idea how find infimum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=3$ we have $\frac{m^4+2n^2}{2m^2-m^2n+n^2}\to-\infty$ as $m\to+\infty$, hence $\inf A=-\infty$.